# Jetpack Compose: Best way of architecting a button that launches asynchronous operation

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

Writing function to compose button that, when clicked, uses deep link to send request to backend with user selection. My understanding of JC is shallow at the moment, but I know enough to use a mutable state change to force a recomposition to call the request code as shown below.

```
        val clicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    OutlinedButton(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        onClick = {
            //runs risk of every recomposition of button causing request to be sent.
            clicked.value = !clicked.value
        }
    ) {
        button.value?.let {
            UIElementMapper(
                uiElement = it
            )
        } ?: Text(text = button.textValue ?: "")
    }
    if (clicked.value) {
        button.ButtonClickAction(buttonClickedState = clicked.value)
    }
```

To run request code here:

```
 @Composable
private fun ChatBotButton.ButtonClickAction(buttonClickedState: Boolean) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    //revise this
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        when (action) {
            is ChatBotButtonAction.PhonecallActionButton -> {
                val callIntent = android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
                callIntent.data =
                    Uri.parse((action as ChatBotButtonAction.PhonecallActionButton).telNumber)
                context.startActivity(callIntent)
            }
            is ChatBotButtonAction.DeeplinkActionButton -> {
                val metadata =
                    Uri.parse((action as ChatBotButtonAction.DeeplinkActionButton).deepLink).getQueryParameters("metadata")
                sendSelectionToChatBot(this@ButtonClickAction, metadata)
            }
            else -> {}
        }
    }
}
```

where sendSelectionToChatBot sends the request to backend and emits result to callback to recompose chatbot screen.
I'm not convinced this is the best approach, and I have concerns that inverting the boolean each time runs a lot of risks.

What is the best way of handling this, and more importantly, *is* writing the button this way inherently flawed in one or another?

Lastly, what is the methodology behind using coroutine scoped operations in compose functions? Are there preferences on where the coroutine scope is derived from? Or inherent issues with placing mutable state callbacks at certain points?

Comment: Use a ViewModel that handles the logic for sending the request to the backend & update its composable function using live data (MVVM)

Comment: @mad_lad I already do that-sendSelectionToChatBot code is exclusively in the ViewModel.